# Regex to extract string between a string and the third occurence of another string in swift?

Tags: regex, swift

I have a large HTML that I must parse it in swift and extract some id's.

**How can I extract from :`data-max-position="NAME-661174248527044608-661303076113014786-BD1UO2FFu9QAAAAAAAAET` the following string `NAME-661174248527044608-661303076113014786` (number between ar not fixed size)?
 I need to get data bwtween data-max-position=" and the third occurrence of "-"**

What regex should I use to give me the information I need?

Until now for another kind of string I have used the following but I don't know what regex should I use for getting what is mentionated in the first part

```
    let query = mystr
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern:"data-name-id=\"(.*?)\"", options: [])
    let tmp = query as NSString
    var results = [String]()

    regex.enumerateMatches(in: query, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, query.characters.count)) { result, flags, stop in
        if let range = result?.rangeAt(1) {
            results.append(tmp.substring(with: range))
        }
    }

    print(results) // ["test", "test1"]
```

that extracts me the stuff inside **"data-name-id"** and the second **"**

Comment: Your regex [does not match the strings provided](https://regex101.com/r/3wc0DF/1). Please clarify.

Comment: `data-max-position` and `data-name-id` are not the same thing.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank You for your answer. What I used from "Until now I have used" is from another use and I wanted to know what regex should I use for what I mentionated in the first part of my qyestion

Comment: Replace `data-name-id` with `data-max-position` in your previous pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I/m really sorry for misunderstandings I've caused. Check out the update.  I need to get data bwtween data-max-position=" and the third occurrence of "-"

Comment: Ok, `pattern:"\\sdata-max-position=\"([^\"-]+-[^\"-]+)"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank You so much. This does returns string until the second "-" but \\sdata-max-position=\"([^\"-]+-[^\"-]+-[^\"-]+) returned what I needed. it's amazing. Can you make an answer with this so I can mark as correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a plain text string in the format you mention, you may use a regex to extract the portion of it:

```
pattern:"\\sdata-max-position=\"([^\"-]+-[^\"-]+-[^\"-]+)"
```

**Details**:

- `\\s` - a whitespace
- `data-max-position=\"` - literal `data-max-position="` substring
- `([^\"-]+-[^\"-]+-[^\"-]+)` - Group 1 (your required value) matching

  - `[^\"-]+` - one or more characters other than `"` and `-`
  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `[^\"-]+-[^\"-]+` - see above.

Note that `[^...]` is a *negated character class that matches any characters that are not defined in the ranges/sets inside the character class.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you